# iPad mini - change ID for App Store

Tags: ipad, apple-id

I have 2 email addresses. The App store uses email address 2 and I can't remember the password for that. Anyway I'd rather it used email address 1. I have checked through Settings>iCloud, Settings>iTunes & App Store and both are logged into email address 1. Settings>Messages was logged into email address 2 but I've signed out of that. Even so I still can't get the App Store to let me login with email address 1.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to for you to do is to go to [the Apple ID management page](https://appleid.apple.com) and reset your password for your Apple ID associated with email address 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already tried that. The problem is that on the App store it's showing one identity and on other Apps it's showing a different one.